# Is there a music player like Winamp?

Tags: software-recommendation, sound, music, mp3

I'm looking for a music player similar to Winamp.

Comment: for those who are searching for a fader or crossfader its in the effects menu on audacious

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's no software in Linux like the current Winamp. If you want something almost similar, try [Audacious](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/audacious), BUT the skined interface ONLY supports winamp 2.x skins. I came from a Winamp environment so I can say this, forget about skins and use the default GTK interface and you'll like it, I know I did :)

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Audacious is very similar to Winamp and it can even use some of the same skins.

```
sudo apt-get install audacious
```

[image]

[Audacious homepage](http://audacious-media-player.org/)

Answer (score 7):

The simplest I've found, that supports WinAMP's 2.x skins is the [QMMP](http://qmmp.ylsoftware.com).

Since I don't need all the bells and whistles (multi-album, fuzzy sort and search, psychic guessing my mood by the way I'm typing...), just plain old fashioned playlists and "open directory" play (I already have my music organized in my HD...), the QMMP it's all I need: plays all the filetypes I have, can play streams, looks for music lyrics and has the same winAMP appearance key bindings. :)
I've tried Audacious, Tomahawk (perhaps not all the time needed to get used to it), and others... And I uninstalled them all: they do much more than I need, so I kept the simplest (still looking for a text-based one! :D). But, for people who needs a lot more, they fill their needs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Visually, Amarok has nothing in common with winamp, but it has all the functionality and more.

Answer (score 0):

There is Rhythmbox or VLC.Rythmbox can also be used to sort your music as winamp does.VLC media player,It can also transcode and convert media files, and act as a streaming server over unicast or multicast and IPv4 or IPv6.but doesnt have a good sort function like rythmbox which can sort music like winamp does.

Answer (score 0):

**An addition to Reda Lazri answer**

You can even have classic look of Winamp in Audacious.

```
wget http://gnome-look.org/CONTENT/content-files/64790-Winamp.tar.gz
tar zxvpf 64790-Winamp.tar.gz
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/audacious/Skins
mv Winamp ~/.local/share/audacious/Skins
```

Answer (score -1):

Try **Tomahawk**. It's a next generation music player. You can call it social music player. It has got great interface. It's feature rich. You will make it your default music player after testing it. It's my challenge. [Tomahawk website](http://www.tomahawk-player.org)

Comment: If it has an album art view in the collection then I'll switch this to my default player. But without that I don't think I can use it :O

Comment: The question was very clear ("like winamp"), but this answer choses to ignore it and go for a "social" music player, "great interface" etc...