# Is there any music player that can hide its main window and only show the playlist?

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, music-player

I use JetAudio basic on Windows and I'd love to have the same modularity that it has on Ubuntu. Specifically, the ability to customize displays and the ability to separate playlist from the main window. I've tried a few but they all looked like iTunes clones, which is really cluttered and has too much information on screen.

It'd also be great if it could play FLAC files but that's not a necessity.

This is the look I'm looking for (just the playlist and nothing else that will clutter the screen when I restore it from minimized status):

[image]

Comment: There might be something here you haven't tried yet https://alternativeto.net/software/jetaudio/

Comment: You're shot looks a bit like [audacious](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25914/is-there-a-music-player-like-winamp) - there are many similar players: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38970/foobar2000-like-music-player

Comment: @Takkat I have not seen one skin which can hide the main window. Hence my question. Also, I've looked at about 10 music players, none of them have that feature by themselves.

Comment: I added another [answer about gmusicbroswer](/a/916142/175814) to the linked question which can be configured to have a minimal play list layout like in the picture. There's a [screenshot](https://gmusicbrowser.org/screenshots/tabbed.png) of one such pre-defined layout that comes with the default installation (but is not the default layout).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks, I'll definitely check it out.